# InvalidSyntax error when using Azure KeyVault References

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-function-app

I am having an issue where I add an Azure KeyVault information as part of my Azure function configuration, but it's giving me an InvalidSyntax error.

In my Azure Function, I go to the Configuration section, in the application tab I click "New application setting". In the Name I added a name like: SomeSecret.. and in the Value I added the path to my azure keyvault, so it looks like this:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://somename.azure.net/secrets/mysecretname/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

I also tried with this

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri="https://somename.azure.net/secrets/mysecretname/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931")
```

I tried with the other syntax, like:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=somename;SecretName=mysecretname;SecretVersion=ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

None of them is working. I made sure that for the Azure function identity, it's added to the KeyVault in Access Policies and it has all required access.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=) is the right way.

So the first format should be no problems. Try to give full access policy and try again.